# Require.js - getting google.maps namespace asynchronously

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, requirejs

[goog](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) plugin seemed a bit to bulky for solving my problem, so I hacked up my own in order to load Google Maps using Google AJAX API loader:

```
define(function() {
  return {
    load : function(name, req, onLoad, config) {
      if (config.isBuild) {
        onLoad(null);
      } else {
        req(['async!http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=abcdefg'], function() {      
          google.load('maps', '2', {
            'other_params': 'sensor=true',
            'callback': onLoad
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I can then return google.maps namespace like this:

```
define(['gm!'], function() {
    return google.maps;
  } 
);
```

Everything works fine, but I wonder: is there a more concise way (besides using goog/custom plugin) to get the namespace?

Comment: Another option: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/src/async.js Use `require("async!//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places")`